# Is BASH dynamic anonymous substring possible?

Tags: bash, substring

Is there a way to do

```
CPU=$(uname -r); echo ${CPU##*-}
```

without declaring a string or a function in BASH?

```
echo ${$(uname -r)##*-}   #<<< I'm looking for this form
```

but it does not work, and

```
[[ $(uname -r) =~ .+-(.+) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

isn't dynamic (I want it nested), and

```
un-r(){ uname -r;};cpu=$(un-r);echo ${cpu##*-}
```

isn't anonymous, (or dynamic).

Comment: This is somewhat of an XY problem; what CPU information do you expect to get from `uname -r`? (That said, no, you can't do this purely with a parameter expansion.)

Comment: not an XY problem. cpu from $(uname -r) was an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't. Zsh lets you write `${$(uname -r)##*-}` with the “obvious” meaning but none of the other common sh-style shells do.

You can of course change the command to get the desired output, e.g.

```
$(uname -r | sed 's/.*-//')
```

but you can't do any further processing of the output inside bash using parameter expansion constructs. If you need that, use a temporary variable. If you want to avoid polluting the shell variables in a function, make the variable local with the `local` builtin (or `declare` or `typeset`). If you need it for a prompt substitution, use `PROMPT_COMMAND` to prepare variable parts of the prompt.